# Convert eps to png with GhostScript on Windows

Tags: windows, conversion, png, ghostscript, eps

If I have some `.eps` files e.g `pic00.eps`, `pic01.eps`, ... Then on Linux I convert them to `.png` files by running the command:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -sOutputFile=pic%02d.png pic*.eps
```

I've just tried on Windows 10 (with `gswin64c` instead of `gs`) and that doesn't work. The error says that:

> pic*.eps is an undefined filename.

What is the command on Windows?

Comment: This works with **git-bash**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Linux because your shell (probably `bash`) is expanding the `*.eps` to a full list of epses *before* ghostscript gets anything.  In Windows, the shell won't do that for you.

In Powershell, I'd do this:

```
$names = (dir *.eps).name
gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 '-sOutputFile=pic%02d.png' $names
```

I've also single-quoted the `-sOutputFile` parameter in case PowerShell were to have trouble with the percent sign.

In cmd batch, I'd do this:

```
for %%i in (*.eps) do (
   gswin64c -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 "-sOutputFile=%%i.pic%02d.png" %%i
)
```

This differs from what Linux and Powershell will do, in that each EPS will trigger a separate ghostscript execution. This is usually okay; using one EPS as a preamble for another is rather unusual.

I also prefixed the PNG filename with the eps name, because the page counter is going to reset for each EPS file, and you don't want pic01.png from the first EPS to get clobbered by the second EPS.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I did my conversions with a R script which launches the command for each single file, in a loop. I'll try your solutions next time.